# In Go is it possible to have a pointer to a member function/method that takes parameters?

Tags: go

If I have

```
type Foo struct {
    // some data
}

func (f *Foo) Op1() bool {
    // perform operation and return a bool
}

func (f *Foo) Op2(other int) bool {
    // perform a different operation using internal data
    // and the passed in parameter(s)
}
```

I know I can store a pointer to the first method.

```
fn := f.Op1
```

and call it

```
if fn(f) { // do something }
```

But what if I want to do the same with `Op2`?
I am currently faking it by defined a wrapper function which takes a `Foo` and the values and calls the operation. But that is a lot of boiler plate code.

Comment: Your syntax for the method pointer call is wrong; if you use a pointer to a method *on an instance*, you needn't pass the instance to it again as a parameter.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks @Adrian. Every example I could find online only showed parameter less members so I was not seeing it was my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using method expressions**

In this case, we get a reference from the type, then you need to pass an instance as the first argument.

```
fn2 := (*Foo).Op2
f := &Foo{}
fn2(f, 2)
```

**Referencing an instance method**

In this case, the instance is already bind to the method and you can just provide the arguments:

```
fn2 := f.Op2
fn2(2)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/e0gUIHzj7Z

Comment: Demonstration of all the permutations (instance method pointer, type method pointer, with and without args): https://play.golang.org/p/2eQEUrFBBI

Comment: Yep. Works. I am still getting used to the capitalization. Uppercase for types, lowercase for instances is what I am accustomed to seeing. It is easy to mix up type Foo and instance variable Foo. Thanks for the demonstration.